# How to pass websocket to child process in Python Tornado?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have a Tornado-server with some Websockethandler. I want to make a pool of workers in order to start a worker as a child process and to pass websocket connection to the worker. After the worker has finished it should send an answer to the client.

```
def worker(message):
    inp_dict = json.loads(message)
    t = inp_dict["time"]
    time.sleep(t)
    return "Hello, World! "*int(t)

class WebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        print("WebSocket opened")

    def on_message(self, message):    
        self.write_message(worker(message))

    def on_close(self):
        print("WebSocket closed")
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Passing connections between processes is not supported. Instead, leave the connections in the main process and use e.g. a `multiprocessing.Queue` to send simple objects (plain old data) back and forth to the child processes.

Comment: Thank you. However, how to send the answer from a child process to the websocket-client?

Comment: For example, as in the code fragment above. How to send the message to the  websocket-client from the worker that has started as a child process?

Comment: There are no child processes in the fragment above. Please make a new question about this with more detail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013515/how-to-send-message-from-the-child-process-to-websocket-client-in-tornado

Comment: @ben-darrel I understand using `multiprocessing.Queue` to send the simple messages back an forth, but how do we leave the connections in the main process?

Comment: The connections can't be moved between processes; they will be "left" in the main process because you can't do anything else with them. Again, please ask a new question with more detail.