# How to reference websocket connections in a multi-processed Python Tornado application?

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket, multiprocessing, tornado

### Versions

- python 2.7.6
- tornado 4.5.3

### What I'm trying to do / The problem:

I have a production-running Tornado application that is forked multiple times using:

```
...
http_server.start()
ioloop = IOLoop.instance()
ioloop.start()
```

For simplicity, let's assume I have 1 RequestHandler for the API and 1 WebSocketHandler for websocket connections. In a single process environment, it is simple enough (I have tested and it works) to instantiate a dictionary (set, list, whatever you fancy) and pass it to both handlers such that the the API can reference instantiated websocket connections and fire `socket.write_message` till the cows come home.

However, I can't get it to work with child processes...

I do have centralized resources I can use (redis, mysql) to maintain state, but I can't find a way to reference the objects other than `self` which is not pickle-able. Assuming we can solve that problem, how do we pass the message to the correct child process which contains the valid connection in memory?

### Useful Reference

I would have loved to have commented "Do you have an example of this?" on the following response by Ben Darnell's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36991995/2012114) but I don't have the reputation. I feel like he was trying to suggest exactly what I'm trying to do!

Comment: Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/hoffrocket/8050711

Comment: Thanks for the example but it still doesn't solve how i would cache the websocket object itself. The data structures provided by multiprocessing that store state (Value, Array, Manager().dict(), etc...) are all incapable of storing such an object. This is where I am most lost.